# Crypto++ library for Symbian

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography, symbian, crypto++

I know that this platform is dead, but for the sake of my old phone, I'm building an app for it.

My application needs to use the Crypto++/CryptoPP library, I have version 5.6.2 of the library built for MSVC2008 and it works with the Simulator and Desktop kits normally.

I've tried to copy the source and header files to a new static library project for Symbian and attempted to build, but I kept getting sequential errors, every time I "fix" one, new one pops up, until I reached a big list of errors I have no idea how to deal with.

Is there any builds or at least instructions on how to build for Symbian?

Comment: I am not aware of any instructions for Symbian. I don't think I've ever seen anyone ask for it. A quick search on the [Crypto++ Users List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cryptopp-users) returned 1 hit, but it was mentioned as an afterthought. I performed the ports for Windows Mobile, Windows Phone, Android and iOS (available on the [Crypto++ Wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page)). Its been my experience that its easier to build using the makefile in a cross-compiled environment; and not within an IDE.

Comment: Do you have any info on what should I possibly look to modify in the makefile and/or the sources?
My last option is to use [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Do you have any reading on Symbian native development kit? If its clearly written, then I might be able to work on a port with you. But I don't have any devices to test with.